# Not getting anything on click of Facebook like button

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook API first time.

I am doing that when user will click a link on "Page1.php" for example "Win Prize" of website so it will come to a "Page2.php".

"Page2.php" will check that user has loged-in in facebook and liked facebook page or not.

IF NOT then shows the facebook like button. when user click this button page will be liked by user and will redirect to "WinPrize.php".

Here is my code of "Page2.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Facebook Page Like</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
//Puted here APP ID
$app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
//Puted here app_secret key
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

//Putted here one pageID
$pageid="XXXXXXXX";

$appurl = "http://www.manektech.net/likeornot/";

//leave it as it is 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user)
{
    try
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $likeID = $facebook->api(
            array( 
                'method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' => 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid="'.$user.'" AND page_id="'.$pageid.'"'
            )
        );

        if(empty($likeID))
        { ?>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

                                        //Putted here my orignal APP ID
                    FB.init({ appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
                    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (href, widget) {
                        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
                    });
                };
                (function () {
                    var e = document.createElement('script');
                    e.type = 'text/javascript';
                    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                    e.async = true;
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                } ());
            //-->
            </script>
            <iframe src="XXX....XXX" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<?php   }
        else
        {
            header("Location: http://www.girlslovecars.com/spinwheel.php");
            exit();
        }   
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        error_log($e);
    }
}

if ($user)
{
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
else
{
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'user_likes,read_stream,publish_stream',
        'redirect_uri' => $appurl
    );
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}

?>

<?php if(!$user){ ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The edge.create event is only fired if you’re embedding the like button using XFBML – it does not work for the iframe version (which you’re using, I suppose, seeing the `<iframe>` element in your code just after your script-block).